# Change plymouth screen resolution?

Tags: 14.04, display-resolution, plymouth

Is it possible to change the screen resolution for plymouth?
I'd like to change it to 1920x1080, because it is a pretty small resolution by now (about 360p) and the plymouth-theme-solar doesn't look very nice.

After booting up, the resolution is just fine (1080p).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be done using the [GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61233/what-does-grub-setting-grub-gfxpayload-linux-text) variable in GRUB's configuration (`/etc/default/grub`). So edit that file using:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Add a line containing:

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1920x1080
```

to the file, save and close.
Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Do remember to check that `1920x1080` is a supported mode for GRUB using the instructions in
[How do I safely change grub2 screen resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54067/how-do-i-safely-change-grub2-screen-resolution)

Comment: That worked so far, the resolution seems to be at 1080p, but there are some thick black borders around the grub and plymouth screen. Can I also somehow get rid of them?