# Fresh install of 20.04 fails on login unless nomodeset is enabled

Tags: system-installation

I have installed 20.04 and unless nomodeset is enabled the screen turns black when I click on the login screen. The computer hardware is as follows:

1. Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-Z170X-UD3 Ultra with a built in Intel 530 graphics controller, 32 GB RAM, and an Intel i7-6700K
2. BIOS is configured for UEFI
3. Ubuntu is installed on a 500GB SSD and is the primary boot target
4. Windows 10 is installed on a 500GB NVME drive

Answer (score 0):

Used information from [What exactly does GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61233/what-exactly-does-grub-gfxpayload-linux-text-do) to set the correct resolution even when nomodeset is enabled. In particular I did the following:

I set GRUB_GFXMODE=2560x1440 in /etc/default/grub then updated grub with sudo update-grub. After rebooting my system is using the correct resolution and appears to be stable.